# how to sort a dictionary using values and also be able to access keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
dic = {'Tea': 35, 'Coffee': 35, 'Chocolate': 10}
```

I want to sort this dictionary by values in descending order, but how can I access keys too?

Sample Code:

```
for x in sorted(dic.values()):
    print(key, dic[key])
```

I'd also like the output to be sorted alphabetically by key when the values are equal.

Expected Output:

```
Coffee 35
Tea 35
Chocolate 10
```

Comment: Hint: look at the `.items()` method instead..

Comment: Could you edit your question to explicitly state the sort order you're looking for? It sounds like you want to sort the values by descending value first, and then alphabetically by name, ascending. Is that right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is [the `dict.items()` method](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict.items), which provides `(key, value)` tuples.

To sort by the value, you then use a `key` method, in this case, an [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to take the second value from the tuple for sorting, then set the `reverse` attribute to get them in the order you want.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> dic={'Tea': 35, 'Coffee': 35, 'Chocolate': 10}
>>> for key, value in sorted(dic.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
...     print(key, value)
... 
Tea 35
Coffee 35
Chocolate 10
```

Edit: If you want to sort by key as a secondary sort, we can simply pass a tuple of values, and Python will sort on the first value, then the second, etc... The only issue is using reverse will mean we get them in the wrong order. As a hack, we simply use the negative version of the value to sort without reverse:

```
>>> for key, value in sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])):
...     print(key, value)
... 
Coffee 35
Tea 35
Chocolate 10
```

Comment: your answer returns `Tea 35 Coffee 35 Chocolate 10`.

Comment: @user1374499 You never defined an order for items with the same value, what rule should be applied in that case? I am presuming alphabetical based on key.

Comment: I posted the desired output with the question.

Comment: @user1374499 With no indication that the ordering of Coffee and Tea was anything but arbitrary - Python dicts are arbitrarily ordered, so an implementation could easily give your output by chance.

Answer (score 7):

One option:

```py
for key in sorted(dic, key=dic.get, reverse=True):
    print(key,dic[key])
```

This sorts the keys of the dictionary, but uses `dic.get` as key function, thereby effectively sorting by value.  Your example output indicates you want to sort in descending order, so I included `reverse=True`.

**Edit**: If your dictionary values are actually counts, you might consider using a `collections.Counter` instead of a dicitonary.  That class has a method `most_common()` which returns the items in the desired order.

Comment: While this works, it does mean you have to retrieve the value from the dictionary twice. While this is a fast operation on a dictionary, it's still a little inelegant.

Comment: it returns `Tea 35
Coffee 35
Chocolate 10`, which is different than what I expected.

Comment: @Lattyware I agree with what you have said but this is a lot more simple than your method. using `key = itemgetter(1)` is not as clear as this imo.

Comment: @Lattyware: I don't aggree it's "inelegant".  It's concise, readable and fast.

Comment: @user1374499: Why do you expect a different output?

Comment: He wants the primary key to be the value, sorted from highest to lowest, and the secondary key to be the name, sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @senderle: How did you figure this out?  It certainly was not mentioned in the question. :)

Comment: No, it wasn't, and the OP should edit the question to be explicit. I just guessed based on the difference between the ordering he requested above and the ordering he complained about in his comment.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I think the alternative is more readable and fast. In the likely case that the value is used more than once, it's also more concise.

Comment: @Lattyware: Your version is absolutely fine as well.  I did upvote it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers which suggest `dict.items()` are partially right. But as you want to include the key in the sorting process (if I understand you correct), you want to reverse the items (which are essentially a tuple `(key, value)`). So use

```
data={'Tea': 35, 'Coffee': 35, 'Chocolate': 10}
for item in sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda it: (-it[1], it[0])):
    print item
```

The `key` parameter gives a function which is used for sorting the items. It converts the items into a key which is then really used for sorting.

In your case, you want a mixed descending / ascending sort, so that the items given here are first turned into

```
(-35, 'Coffee')
(-35, 'Tea')
(-10, 'Chocolate')
```

and printed in that order. (The replacement process just happens for sorting purposes, the items actually returned are the original ones.)

Comment: This won't work - for one, it'll go from smallest to highest, for two, the lambda will only get one argument.

Comment: Yes, but now it is merely a duplicate of my answer.

Comment: I edited mine before you changed yours, hence why I posted on yours highlighting the issue.

Comment: Ok, sorry - then I didn't see yours, probably because we edited ours on nearly the same time...

Comment: No problem - it was a good answer (the same as mine, so I would think so) - and these things happen. Not your fault, I know it wasn't plagiarism or anything, just coincidence.